# how to do a size changing by variable value in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

what I would like to do is a heatmap style graph but that also changes its size by another variable, in this case I would use the heatmap for log2FC and the difference in size for the pvalue.
I couldn't find anything that looked like this, so I tried to create my own and came up with this.

```
library(ggplot2)
data$gene_name <- as.factor(data$gene_name)

heatmap <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = med, y = gene_name)) +
                        geom_tile(aes(fill = log2FoldChange,size = pvalue))+


 theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")
```

However, the pvalue squares appear the same size.
What I would like is for the graph to be on its side (in this case horizontally and for the squares to change size with the pvalue). It is possible??

the date example:

```
gene_name   log2FoldChange  pvalue  med
gene 1               1,13   0,0023  ATV
gene 2               2,79   0,0014  ATV
gene 3               1,27   0,0204  ATV
gene 20              0,54   0,0023  PEN
gene 21             -0,59   0,0356  PEN
gene 22              1,97   0,0243  PEN
gene 23              1,01   0,0001  PEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `geom_tile` the `size` aesthetic only controls the size of the line (now replaced by `linewidth` in newer versions of `ggplot2`). The tiles themselves cannot really change size as their filling of the whole space is part of how that geom represents data. You can use `geom_shape` with the squares to represent p-values by size instead, playing around with `scale_size_continuous` to match how best to present your data:

```r
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gene_name,   ~log2FoldChange,  ~pvalue,  ~med,
  "gene 1",               1.13,   0.0023,  "ATV",
  "gene 2",               2.79,   0.0014,  "ATV",
  "gene 3",               1.27,   0.0204,  "ATV",
  "gene 20",              0.54,   0.0023,  "PEN",
  "gene 21",             -0.59,   0.0356,  "PEN",
  "gene 22",              1.97,   0.0243,  "PEN",
  "gene 23",              1.01,   0.0001,  "PEN"
)

library(ggplot2)
data$gene_name <- as.factor(data$gene_name)

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = med, y = gene_name)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = log2FoldChange, size = pvalue), shape = 22)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 20)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make your approach work you have to map on the `width` and `height` aesthetic of `geom_tile`. However, in general this requires to rescale the variable mapped on these aesthetics to a range of e.g. 0 to 1. An advantage of this approach is that you don't have to fiddle around with setting the range of the `size` scale as in Andy's approach. However, one drawback is that you will not get a legend and as a second drawback, if you want squares you have to use `coord_fixed` or `coord_equal`.

Note: It's of course possible to use a different range for the rescaling but I would recommend to not use a maximum value > 1 as this will in general result in overlapping tiles.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data$gene_name <- as.factor(data$gene_name)
data$pvalue_scaled <- scales::rescale(data$pvalue, to = c(0, 1))

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = med, y = gene_name)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = log2FoldChange, width = pvalue_scaled, height = pvalue_scaled)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]